# Microphone response question

Tags: technique, microphones

When we have a particular microphone and we use it to record vocals, does the sweet spot of that mike change with different types of voices? Or does it stay situated in one spot?

Answer (score 4):

The sweet spot or pickup pattern of the mic doesn’t change, but different vocalists have different projection patterns, so you might want to line the sweet spot of the mic up with a different part of the singers body. Lower placement makes the mic more chesty, higher sounds more nasal. Distance also makes a difference. Farther away has less bass and less mouth noise and can pick up a more balanced tone. Closer is the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

a mics sweet spot isnt nearly as important as a vocalist understnding things like proximity;inflection; projection and a myriad of other things that determines the quality of a track..... ill take a skilled vocalist on a shure 57 anyday vs a bad singer on akg c4000 condenser.... the better mic only picks up the untrained mistakes.   but this alas'''''is how we learn